# How can I convert the Kafka message timestamp to date and time format in C#?

Tags: c#, kafka-topic, confluent-kafka-dotnet

In my C# code I programmed a consumer with Confluent Kafka. I am reading the timestamp of the message and want to convert it to the know time and date format. I tried following code but get always Error: System.FormatException: String 'Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. How can I fix this problem?

```
public void Kafka_consumer()
{
   //some code for getting message from Kafka topic
   Kafka_TimeStamp_string = consumeResult.Message.Timestamp.ToString();
   TimeStamp_dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Kafka_TimeStamp_string, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: There's no way this would work unless `Timestamp` was already a DateTime (in which case no code is needed)  or a string in ISO format (in which case ToString() isn't needed) . What's the actual type of `Timestamp` ?

Comment: Is `Timestamp` a `Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp` object? That has a [UtcDateTime](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/a67bd6c06b7eef4293e6476d9ff6f3e93f0e4cd9/src/Confluent.Kafka/Timestamp.cs#L120) property. There's no reason for any conversion. `TimeStamp_dateTime =consumeResult.Message.Timestamp.UtcDateTime` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp.UtcDateTime`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/a67bd6c06b7eef4293e6476d9ff6f3e93f0e4cd9/src/Confluent.Kafka/Timestamp.cs#L120):

```
DateTime dt = consumeResult.Message.Timestamp.UtcDateTime;
```

There is no reason to convert it to string even if the type had `ToString` overloaded (currently it does not so you get the default one which returns the type name).